# how to send data from angular function to codeigniter view to model

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

```
$scope.editrc = function(id)
{
    $http.get('admissionsourcecontroller/editadID/'+id).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.form = data;
});
}
```

I have created one angularjs function, when I click on button I gets id of that  record then I'll pass to codeigniter controller

```
public function editadID($id)
{   
    $query = $this->db->select('Name,id')   
            ->where('MasterValueID', $id)
            ->get('blog');
    echo json_encode($query->row());
}
```

I have get result of that record

My view file is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-data" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="POST" name="editItem" role="form" ng-submit="saveEdit()">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Registration</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input ng-model="form.Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="title" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now I want to send all data to view for model, how ??

Comment: I think their is confusion in between ```model``` and ```modal```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `JSON` with `$http.post`

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'admissionsourcecontroller/editadID/', 
    data: form,  //this is where you set the data object you want to send
}).then(
    function(res) {
        console.log('succes !');
        //do something here
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log('error...');
    }
);
```

Comment: thnx Miqe Now How I take edit model form value and pass angular saveEdit() function and then  pass my codeIgniter controller  function , plz describe briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is a client side MVC framework which runs on javascript.

Similarly, CodeIgniter is a Server side MVC Framework that runs on php.

There can be ways to pass data from angular to `CIModel` as you are searching for it. But the ideal way to do it, following the best practices is to not to use the `CI` on client side at all.

Making 2 folders

1. Client
2. Server

in the root of your project directory.

Setup the Angularjs in your **client**. Code its views controllers and factories.

Setup CI in your server folder. Configure your database with your CIModels and make different controllers on the basis of the modules you make on the client side.

Now make request from clientside factories to the server side controllers. That is, APIs.

Do the data passing by JSON or XML whatever suits you.

That will be the optimum use of both.